# Generate js file from proto file with protoc v21.1

Tags: protocol-buffers, commonjs, protoc

Command used -

```
protoc.exe --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. employees.proto
```

Error -

```
'protoc-gen-js' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Version Used -

```
protoc.exe --version                              
libprotoc 3.21.1

--js_out: protoc-gen-js: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```